# Como faço pra exibir variaveis numa página django?

Tags: django, web-scraping

Eu sou novo no django e estou tirar algumas informações de uma página web usando lxml. Gostaria de saber como faço pra exibir os valores na minha página web.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from django.shortcuts import render


def list_data(request):  
    return render(request, 'data.html', {})


def get_idhm(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    idhm = tree.xpath('//*[@id="responseMunicipios"]/ul/li[6]/div/p[2]/text()')
    return idhm[0]


def get_population(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    values = tree.xpath('//*[@id="responseMunicipios"]/ul/li[3]/div/p[2]/text()')
    return values[0]
```

essa é a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você pode ver no exemplo que mostrou, tem um metodo chamado `list_data`. Nele você renderiza data.html e um dicionario vazio. Nesse dicionário você pode colocar os valores que serão exibidos no HTML. Segue exemplo:

**views.py**

```
def list_data(request):  
    return render(request, 'data.html', {"message": "Hello World"})
```

**data.html**

```
<p>{{message}}</p>
```